# How do I reset my Android Samsung phone back to factory settings?

Tags: applications, samsung

How do I reset my Android Samsung phone back to factory settings?  I do not know how or why or what one of my multiple messaging apps has the bug but I am not able to receive a text message from Facebook to reacquire my Facebook account.

Comment: Search in settings or internet for your specific model for factory-reset. On my Pixel, it is in System - reset options but Samsung UI is different